# Generate the token that can be validated against RSA signing key in azure

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework, jjwt

I am using an Azure B2C custom policy where I want to send an invitation link to the user, with JWT token containing necessary details.

I need to create the JWT token in JAVA. Using the jjwt library I was successful in creating a token using HS256, but later found out that I will require the token to be signed using RSA256.
I have the TokenSigningKeyContainer policy key in Azure AD B2C, with below fields

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "tenantID": "<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com",
        "storageKeyId": "B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer",
        "updatedUtc": "10/16/2019 2:12:11 PM"
    },
    "keys": [
        {
            "kid": "<key_id>",
            "use": "sig",
            "key_ops": [
                "sign"
            ],
            "kty": "RSA",
            "e": "<>",
            "n": "<n_value>"
        }
    ]
}
```

This seems to be the public key to verify the generated token, sent in the invitation link.

What I need to know is how I can get the necessary details for the private key, to sign the JWT token?

Comment: By coincidence, I was just reading [this article](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite). It seems to be what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But post cert creation, it is following the steps needed for the .Net to use the cert to sign the JWT token while what we need is to do this with Java.

Answer (score 0):

AzureAD B2C doesn't reveal the private key once it is uploaded. By using apis, you can get access to only metadata, by using wellknown metadata discovery points, you can get public keys.

You need to store the cert with encrypted data store (such as Azure Key Vault) and use it while signing the token. According to the sample, you don't need to upload it to the AADB2C either.